# What is "a very proper wife" referring to in this sentence?

Tags: interpretation

> She will make him a very proper wife -Pride218-

Does it mean *she will become a proper wife*? Or *she will make him turn into a woman(wife)*?

I think that the sentence above goes like this:

**He quit smoking cold turkey.**
This could mean **he quit smoking + he was cold turkey.**

So, cold turkey describes the man.

I guess also the given sentence in which "a very proper wife" is embedded has the same structure as the example I provided.

Are those right?

Comment: I'm guessing it's **proper** in the sense of **appropriate**. But it's difficult to tell... do you have a link to the full source for the statement?

Comment: Also, the statement "He was cold turkey" makes absolutely no sense unless you're saying that something was **actually** or **figuratively** a cold turkey... but I'm not sure what that would be.

Comment: @Catija It's from "[Pride and Prejudice](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Pride_and_Prejudice)".

Comment: @MARamezani Of course it is. :P That's what I thought but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: He stated that his love for her was neither sudden nor accidental, and she replied that he would make a better lawyer than lover.   "Make" = be|achieve. Compare "He has all the makings of a lawyer." Qualities that would allow one to be {something}.

Comment: To expand on your other sentence: In "He quit smoking cold turkey", the "cold turkey" refers to the method rather than the person. It's the same as saying, "He quit smoking suddenly, without any aids to help him quit."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "I like her appearance", said Elizabeth, struck with other ideas. "She looks sickly and cross. -- Yes, she will do for him very well. She will make him a very proper wife."

At this point in the story, Elizabeth is being a bit mean. She's talking to herself and has heard that Miss De Bourgh was intended to marry Mr. Darcy from their childhoods.

She's not particularly fond of Darcy's actions towards her older sister, Jane, and thinks that he deserves to have someone who has the seeming of propriety (her esteemed family background and inheritance) because it seems to be all he cares about (over the actual feelings the two people have for each other).

So, what she's saying is that, based on **his** preference for matching people (in marriage) who are of the same social stature, and **his** mean nature (in her eyes at the time) Miss. De Bourgh will be an **appropriate** match for his sensibilities and personality.

It's sort of her saying "*He'll get what he deserves*" because she's angry and doesn't want him to be happy.

Comment: You are right. The sentence that i provided was not enough for asking question. espeacially that sentence were needed more information of what happenings have been occured before saying like that

Answer (score 2):

I would take this sentence to literally mean:

**She will be a good wife for him.**

To describe something as 'proper' can by synonymous with 'excellent' or sometimes even 'apt'.

In this case, 'very proper' serves as an adjective describing 'She'.

The use of the verb 'to make' is typical of UK/British english to be synonymous with 'will be' when used in this context.

Also, good luck for reading pride and prejudice. I have stopped reading it many times, despite my best intentions.

Comment: In this case, I think 'proper' should be equated with correct, as in correct behavior. Elizabeth is thinking that Miss De Burgh will do everything that society expects of her. That may or not equate to being a 'good wife' for Darcy.

Comment: Good clarification mkennedy. I believe we are thinking the same thing, but I forget what parts of my speech are regional and/or idiomatic. Where I grew up a 'good wife' would have been one that 'does everything society expects of her'. Sometimes oversimplification brings out the difference in language.

Comment: I believe the meaning of "proper" here is "Suitable for a specified or implicit purpose or requirement" (OED).

Answer (score 1):

Others have explained your *proper wife* sentence, but we need to clarify the *cold turkey* sentence.

The phrase *cold turkey* is a two-word adverbial expression meaning "abruptly".

So, the sentence:

> He quit smoking cold turkey.

does **not** mean "he quit smoking + he was cold turkey." Rather, it describes the manner in which he quit smoking. I could say, for example:

> Bob quit smoking gradually, by smoking two less cigarettes per day every few days, until he was down to zero. But his friend Frank quit smoking cold turkey.

That means Frank just stopped smoking one day, and never smoked again.

Comment: Thank you for giving me more clear sense of aspect for structures :)

Answer (score 0):

It means "She will become a very proper wife."

*make* is the synonym/has the meaning of *become* in his context. *make* and *become* are synonyms in a particular context.

Comment: I appreciate your valuable answer

Comment: You should upvote the answers you accept, and mark the best one as "resolved".